# VLAN setup on MikroTik wired router + TP-Link WiFi AP fails to connect to internet

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, vlan, mikrotik-routeros

I have a MikroTik hEX router and TP-Link EAP225v3 wireless access point. I created VLAN with id 11 on the router, and created an SSID that uses vlan 11 on the AP. When i try to connect to the wifi, it fails to get an IP address, and says "no internet connection". My other SSID (without VLAN) works just fine.

For router setup i followed [this](https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:Interface/VLAN) manual:

```
/interface vlan
add name=VLAN11 vlan-id=11 interface=ether1 disabled=no

/ip address
add address=192.168.10.3/24 interface=VLAN11

/ip pool
add name=dhcp_pool11 ranges=192.168.10.5-192.168.10.254

/ip dhcp-server
add address-pool=dhcp_pool11 disabled=no interface=VLAN11 name=dhcp11

/ip dhcp-server network
add address=192.168.10.0/24 dns-server=8.8.8.8 gateway=192.168.10.3
```

On the EAP225 the config is fairly straight forward:
[image]

It seems I'm missing a step or two here. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Does it work on your PC if you use VLAN 11?

Comment: I don't have a PC, all my devices are wireless

Comment: Hmm since when does tp-link have native vlaning in their firmware? Can you add the tp-link firmware revision?

Comment: @Tim_Stewart it's already there: TP-Link EAP225v3

Comment: Ether1 is also carrying the native vlan right? And setup as a trunk port?

Comment: I think I got it working. The problem was I was adding them to ether1, when it should've been ether2 (it's designated as ether2-master)

Comment: @Tim_Stewart I'm really new to this. how would I know which port is trunk? I only have one VLAN, would I even need a port set as trunk?

Comment: You mean you have one **tagged** vlan. 802.1q always has a native vlan. It's usually untagged and designated as vlan1. Trunk port means a port that carries multiple vlans simultaneously.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you for your help!